# Viewing Workspace variables in python like in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, variables, view, workspace

I am trying to move to Python from MATLAB to conduct my research work. I am trying to figure out if there is any way by which I can view the Workspace variables on execution (As shown in the red box in the image : http://postimg.org/image/4wp5qzkuj/ ) as MATLAB does in Python. I am using the Spyder IDE for my work.

Thank you !

CSA

Comment: That would be Spyder's [variable explorer](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/variableexplorer.html)

Answer (score 2):

Spyder offers this,

in the Mac version it is under view -> panes -> variable explorer

I do not know where to find it in other OS

hope to help you,
Glostas

Comment: Thanks ! But, I am still unable to see the class variables in the variable explorer !!

Comment: I am not sure if you can do this there